# Вызов окна из другого окна в фоновом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день , такая проблема , есть таймер,он каждую секунду выполняет метод асинхронно (asyc/await/Task) и в этом методе нужно создать окно и показать его , что-то вроде уведомления , но ловлю System.InvalidOperationException: 'Вызывающим потоком должен быть STA, поскольку этого требуют большинство компонентов UI.'

```
 private async void ShowMagic(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (ListofNearCalls != null)
            {
                NotificationWindow temp = new NotificationWindow();
            temp.Show();
            }
        });      
    }
```

Comment: Зачем тут вся эта асинхронщина? Все, что нужно внутри метода - это  `new NotificationWindow().ShowDialog();`

Comment: Что бы асинхронно проверять , наступило ли нужное время , для вызова окна , в примере урезал проверки , что бы не нагромождать код

Comment: Вы понимаете, что даже если вы запустите окно в другом потоке (что не стоит делать), то ваша таска все равно закончится сразу при запуске окна и не будет ждать, когда окно закроется. Замените вашу конструкцию на то, что я вам написал и все дела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно подсказывает @tym32167, вам не нужен новый поток. Если вы хотите показать окно через некоторое время, используйте

```
private async void ShowMagic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000); // подождали две секунды
    // тут мы снова в главном потоке
    new NotificationWindow().Show();
}
```

Если вам перед `Task.Delay` нужны какие-то несложные вычисления, вы можете сделать их прямо там. Если вычисления сложные, нужно вынести их в подтаск:

```
private async void ShowMagic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = await Task.Run(() => { тут вычисление промежутка времени });
    // тут мы снова в главном потоке
    await Task.Delay(ts); // подождали сколько надо
    // и опять в главном потоке
    new NotificationWindow().Show();
}
```